# How do I remove extra margin space generated by inline blocks?

Tags: css

I am using this css to format two columns but I am still getting margin space between two. I can eliminate it with use of `margin-left: -4px;` or some such. Is there a more elegant way to do this or is there something wrong with the CSS code?

```
div.col1{
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  width 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #272727;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

div.col2{
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 900px;
  height: 100%;

  width: 620px;
  margin: 0px;

  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @Pavel: this site works a little different to other forums. When you find a helpful answer, you are supposed to upvote it by clicking in the up arrow next to it. If that question solved your problem, you should click on the bog checkmark next to it and the question will be marked as resolved. No need to add the [Resolved] to the title of the question. Welcome to http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: heh thanks, I dont have the karma to upvote it just yet :)

Comment: @Pavel: but you can select an accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Perhaps you have:

```
<div class="col1">
    Stuff 1
</div>
<div class="col2">
    Stuff 2
</div>
```

? If so then this is probably a whitespace problem (it turns out whitespace does matter in html). This should fix it:

```
<div class="col1">
    Stuff 1
</div><div class="col2">
    Stuff 2
</div>
```

Comment: To be more precise - it matters here because the blocks are treated as inline (due to inline-block)

Comment: Nice catch! I wouldn't easily find it.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer requires altered markup (wasn't that what CSS was supposed to fix? :-/) and won't fork for post-processed/tidied markup (like that generated in ASP.NET WebForms).

Comment: @user166390 The OP is specifically setting the DIVs to be inline elements, so they're going to behave like inline elements and altered markup is necessary to have them butted against each other with no space (unless you set a negative margin on the 2nd column DIV). CSS isn't going to change how the W3C specs handle inline elements. If you want to accomplish this without altering the markup then you'll need to float the elements to the left.

Answer (score 20):

A simple `font-size:0` to the parent element will work.

Comment: this has a bug on android

Comment: it works font size 0 on parent element and then on subelement set to 1.5rem for example

Answer (score 10):

The elements with attribute `inline-block` will behave as if they are inline (hence the name), and therefore any whitespace encountered will be treated as a space. For example:

```
<div></div><div></div>
```

will be rendered differently to

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

[See a live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/4H8Fn/)

**You can solve this problem using HTML as follows:**

Either place all your elements on the same line, i.e.

```
<div>
    // CONTENT
</div><div>
    // CONTENT
</div><div>
    // CONTENT
</div>
```

or use HTML comments to remove the spaces

```
<div>
    //CONTENT
</div><!--
--><div>
    //CONTENT
</div>
```

**You can solve this problem using CSS as follows:**

Set the attribute `font-size: 0` on the parent, i.e.

```
parent {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0
}
parent * {
    font-size: 12px
}
```

or set the attribute `zoom: 1` on the parent, i.e.

```
parent {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, to fix this without changing the formatting of your source code, you can create an additional element.

If you were doing this in a list it would look like:

```html
<ul >
    <li>
      <a href="#">Solutions Overview</a>
    </li>       
</ul>   


<style type="text/css">             
    ul {word-spacing:-1em;}
    ul li a{word-spacing:0;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply float:left and that will remove the space so the text doesn't have to be on 1 line.

Comment: If only `float:left` didn't have entirely different semantics ..

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, some helpful techniques can be found listed here:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Making the parent element `font-size: 0` will also resolve the issue.

```html
<div class="col-set">
    <div class="col1">
        Stuff 1
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        Stuff 2
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.col-set { font-size: 0; }    
.col-set > div { font-size: 12px; }
```

Answer (score -5):

You should also specify:

```
padding: 0;
```

Comment: yes, i have dotted red borders showing the element's locations. I've tried firebug, but it does not attribute spacing to any element style.