# Nav bar border issue

Tags: css, border

I am working on a new home page, trying to avoid images as much as possible and I have a slight issue with the borders on the Nav bar.  I can't really think of a way to get the sides of the borders to link into each other with padding.  At the moment the sides are not touching so it doesn't look continuos.  I may be missing something obvious but I can't think of a way to meet them up.  Any one have any ideas?

The only way I can think to solve this is with classes on each of the li elements but am wondering if there is an optional way.

Here is a Fiddle for you to check :

http://jsfiddle.net/WZF4M/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the following in li styling? A tweak though; not tested in all browsers.

```
li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: -5px; /*Add this*/
    padding: 11px 12px 11px 12px;
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;
}
```

Option 2:-

A more elegant solution right here at SO.

[How do I remove extra margin space generated by inline blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801589/how-do-i-remove-extra-margin-space-generated-by-inline-blocks)

You may have to make changes to your html for this.

```
<ul>
    <li>Test</li><li>Apple</li><li>Cat</li><li>Dog</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This would be the accepted answer if I could get it to work in Firefox.  It's tabbing down to the next line for some reason :/

Comment: Yep that did the trick.  Firefox is still being a bit of a pain with the bottom border overlapping by 1px compared to other browsers but the whitespace issue sure is strange!

Answer (score 1):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WZF4M/4/)**. I floated the list items left instead of displaying them inline. That removes the gaps between them. Then I positioned the list itself relatively and move it up slightly.

CSS:

```
ul{
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    top:-14px;
}
li{
    float:left;
    padding: 11px 12px 11px 12px;
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to give this a more continuous feel is to only use `border-right` on your `li` elements in your menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/WZF4M/3/

I have updated your fiddle.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.