# Why div and Nav under getting displayed as block?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to create a complex header for my website. Right now this header is composed for two section.

1. Logo - Using a div for this. 15% of header. display: inline-block
2. Navigation - Using nav for this. 85% of header. display: inline-block

But in browser I am seeing logo on top of nav as kept in stack.

How to get rid of this issue.

Following is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- main css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id='logo'>
                <p>LOGO</p>
            </div>
            <nav>
                klkdfglkdfjklg
            </nav>
        </header>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
**CSS**

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

header {
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;  
    width: 15%;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why not put the div inside the nav?

Comment: `<nav> <div id="logo">Logo</div> Other items </nav>`

Comment: Dont put the DIV inside the nav, unless it is part of the navigation (which it isn't by your markup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case nav and div are inside your header element and the div is on the top of nav. You can try

**CSS**

```
nav {
    float:left;
}
#logo {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand it looks like you want the logo and nav side by side.

In your code you have written only display:inline-block, with this you also need to add vertical-align:top/bottom/middle.

Apart from this, a simple solution is using float left/right according to requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='logo'><p>LOGO</p></div><nav>klkdfglkdfjklg</nav>
```

remove the newline space between div and nav tags

you can read on this article

[How do I remove extra margin space generated by inline blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801589/how-do-i-remove-extra-margin-space-generated-by-inline-blocks)

i recommend also using reset css 
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/